Allow multiple types for one property when deserializing json using System.Text.Json
I am expecting that particular property in the incoming data would be either an array of integers or a string. What is the proper way to define this condition it in my model?
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class TestClass
{
    // this field should either be a string or an array. Nothing else
    [JsonPropertyName("values")
    public string? values { get; set; } = null; 
}

For reference, in Python, I can do it like so, and can set my values property to either a string or a list of int:
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import List

class TestClass(BaseModel):
    values: List[int] | str = Field(None, alias="values")

Thank you in advance

C# doesn't support discriminated unions. If you need them you might look into F#, which has that feature.

@dbc, thank you.. so, what is the appropriate way to implement something like this in C#?

Is your JSON format fixed in advance, or can you change it?  If fixed, can you share a sample?

not fixed.   there is room for change.  values property is actually either unencoded array of values, or same array encoded into a string by the client (base64 for example).  there is another property that tells the server the encoding method client used for the values property.

C# does not support the property to have multiple (data) types. For your case, I would suggest having two properties to store the value with different types.
Apply the values property with the JsonElement type to allow accepting dynamic JSON (type) value so that you can deserialize it into specified type later on.
Approach 1: Deserialize with getter
public class TestClass
{
    [JsonInclude]
    [JsonPropertyName("values")]
    public JsonElement? values { get; set; } = null; //this field should either be a string or an array.  nothing else.
    
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string StringValue 
    { 
        get
        {
            if (values.HasValue && values.Value.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.String)
            {
                return values.Value.ToString();
            }
            
            return null;
        }       
    }
    
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int[] IntegerValues
    { 
        get
        {
            if (values.HasValue && values.Value.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Array)
            {
                try
                {
                    return values.Value.Deserialize<int[]>();
                }
                catch
                {
                    return null;    
                }
            }
            
            return null;
        }
    }
}

Approach 2: Implement JsonConverter
public class TestClassConverter : JsonConverter<TestClass>
{
    public override TestClass Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            TestClass value = new TestClass();

            JsonElement root = JsonElement.ParseValue(ref reader);
            JsonElement values = root.GetProperty("values");

            value.values = values;

            switch (values.ValueKind)
            {
                case JsonValueKind.String:
                    value.StringValue = values.ToString();
                    break;

                case JsonValueKind.Array:
                    value.IntegerValues = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<int[]>(values);
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new JsonException("Unsupported values type");
            }

            return value;
        }


    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        TestClass value,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            throw new NotImplementedException();
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(TestClassConverter))]
public class TestClass
{
    [JsonInclude]
    [JsonPropertyName("values")]
    public JsonElement? values { get; set; } = null; //this field should either be a string or an array.  nothing else.
    
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int[] IntegerValues { get; set; }
}


Demo Approach 1 @ .NET Fiddle Demo Approach 2 @ .NET Fiddle

thank you.  this is above and beyond.  i am playing with both.  if you dont mind follow-up question.  my controller method is [HttpPost(Name = "test_post")]  public int Post([FromBody]TestClass testclass).  method #1 fails for me because either StringValue or IntegerValues are required, depending on what is in the json

From what I understand based on your requirement, you want to enforce that the values received must be a string/ an array of integers? If yes, I think you need to implement IValidatableObject to your model so that the values can be deserialized and assign to either StringValue or IntegerValues. Otherwise, you return the failed validation indicating that the values property is required or fails to have the expected data type. Correct me if I misunderstood. Thanks.

yes.  this is precisely what i am trying to do.  field values should be able to accept either string OR an array of ints.  Im looking into implementing IValidatableObject as you suggested, but I'm having trouble figuring out how would my controller method would deserialise the request, How would it call the Validate method?

Hi, I believe the model validation including IValidatableObject will be automatically executed after the model body deserialization and before reaching the controller method body. You can try placing a breakpoint in the Validate method. Both model deserialization (Model binding) and validation are handled by the .NET Core framework automatically.

You are looking for something like F#'s discriminated union functionality, however nothing like that has been implemented in the language yet.  See the C# language proposal Discriminated unions / enum class for a discussion.
Lacking that, you could make your own:
[JsonConverter(typeof(DiscriminatedUnionConverter))]
public struct DiscriminatedUnion<T1, T2>
{
    readonly object? value;
    readonly int index;
    
    public DiscriminatedUnion(T1 type1) => (this.value, this.index) = (type1, 1);
    public DiscriminatedUnion(T2 type2) => (this.value, this.index) = (type2, 2);
    
    public object? Value => value;
    public int Index => index;
    public Type? Type => index switch
    {
        1 => typeof(T1),
        2 => typeof(T1),
        _ => default,
    };
    
    public static implicit operator DiscriminatedUnion<T1, T2>(T1 value) => new(value);
    public static implicit operator DiscriminatedUnion<T1, T2>(T2 value) => new(value);
}

class DiscriminatedUnionConverter : JsonConverterFactory
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => 
        typeToConvert.IsGenericType && typeToConvert.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DiscriminatedUnion<,>);
    public override JsonConverter? CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (typeToConvert.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DiscriminatedUnion<,>))
            return (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(DiscriminatedUnionConverter<,>).MakeGenericType(typeToConvert.GetGenericArguments()))!;
        throw new NotImplementedException(typeToConvert.FullName);
    }
}

class DiscriminatedUnionConverter<T1, T2> : JsonConverter<DiscriminatedUnion<T1, T2>>
{
    record DTO<T>(int type, T? value);

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DiscriminatedUnion<T1, T2> union, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        switch (union.Index)
        {
            case 1 : JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, new DTO<T1>(union.Index, (T1?)union.Value)); break;
            case 2 : JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, new DTO<T2>(union.Index, (T2?)union.Value)); break;
            default: JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, new { type = union.Index }); break;
        }
    }
    
    public override DiscriminatedUnion<T1, T2> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DTO<JsonElement>>(ref reader, options) switch
        {
            { type : 1 } dto => dto.value.Deserialize<T1>(options)!,
            { type : 2 } dto => dto.value.Deserialize<T2>(options)!,
            _ => default,
        };
}

And then modify your class as follows:
public class TestClass
{
    [JsonPropertyName("values")]
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public DiscriminatedUnion<string?, int []> values { get; set; }
}

And now you will be able to do something like:
var inputTest = new TestClass { values = "hello" };

Or
var inputTest = new TestClass { values = new int[] {1, 2, 3 }};

And then
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(inputTest);

var outputTest = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestClass>(json);
switch (outputTest?.values.Value)
{
    case string s : Console.WriteLine($"Value is {s}"); break;
    case int [] a : Console.WriteLine($"Value is {string.Join(',', a)}."); break;
}

The resulting JSON will look like:
{
  "values": {
    "type": 1,
    "value": "hello"
  }
}

Or
{
  "values": {
    "type": 2,
    "value": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  }
}

Demo fiddle here.
Notes:

If you require three or more discriminated union types within the same union, you will need to introduce additional generic types DiscriminatedUnion<T1, T2, ..., TN> similarly to how there are multiple generic ValueTuple<T1, T2, ..., TN> types.

There are a many other 3rd party discriminated union implementations available for you to choose from, see e.g. Discriminated union in C# or Discriminated Unions in C# - Maarten Balliauw {blog} for some.  Whichever one you choose, you would likely need to write a custom JsonConverter.

Honestly this seems more trouble than it is worth.  Since your JSON format is flexible, if your TestClass can contain either a string or an int [] array, just use separate properties for each:
public class TestClass
{
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    public string? StringValue { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    public int []? IntValues { get; set; }
}



